# Yii Grid, multiple management rows

Tags: yii, rows

i have a questions about managament rows in grid. For example we have food/cost table like:

```
Fruit | cost
------------
Apple | 10$
Bannan| 5$
```

We can create form like:

```
<form>
<input type='text' name='Fruits[0][fruit] value='Apple' /> <input type='text' name='Fruits[0][cost]  value='10$' /> <br>
<input type='text' name='Fruits[1][fruit] value='Bannan' /> <input type='text' name='Fruits[1][cost]  value='5$' />
</form>
```

And save all it like:

```
 if ($is_new)
    if(isset($_POST['Fruits'])) {
      foreach ($_POST['Fruits'] as $fruit) {
        $model = new Fruit();
        $model->attributes = $fruit;
        $model->save();
      }
    }
} else { //here code for update, $model->load()... }
```

All fine, we can update both rows... But that if i want add new? All fine method above make all good, but what if i delete 1 row? In my base i will have 2 rows, but i need only 1.

Here 2 ways i see:
1. Delete all fruits from databse on every update when POST count != databse count
2. We can load database rows, write loop, check every row... but its so hard, so many code...

How you manage new and deleted rows?

Answer (score 0):

Use Yii data handlers to print results, like 'CGridView' :
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView/